# Can I determine if mouse button is already pressed to change cursor?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser, mouse-cursor

I am enabling drag and drop for one control in my SL 5 OOB app.

However, when the user is dragging a file, the cursor is the "copy file' cursor everywhere over my app.

Can I determine if, when the cursor enters my app, the left mouse button is down, and change the cursor appropriately (droppable or not droppable)?

Thanks for any insights...